# Modify a command in WebBrowser with button in another form VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in `form2`

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    If WebBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains(TextBox2.Text) Then
        Button1.Hide()
        GroupBox1.Hide()
    ElseIf WebBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains(TextBox3.Text) Then
        Form3.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

I have a button in `form1`. When I press the button, I need the line `Form3.Show()` to change to another form.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In `form2`:

```
Public SelectedForm As Form

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    If WebBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains(TextBox2.Text) Then
        Button1.Hide()
        GroupBox1.Hide()
    ElseIf WebBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains(TextBox3.Text) Then
        If(SelectedForm, Form3).Show()
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

In the button click for `form1`:

```
Form2.SelectedForm = Form4 'The exact form name you want here isn't shown in the question.
```